# Displaying repeated images next to list items

Tags: html, css

I have a list of Indian dishes that I've copied from a takeaway menu, and I need to display between zero and five chili peppers to the right of some of them to indicate if it's a hot dish. I also need to display a 'V' next to vegetarian dishes. I've purchased a couple of SVGs, scaled and converted to PNG.

I'd like to do the list styling using CSS; the following works if I only want to display **EITHER** a single chili **OR** a 'V' (.list-unstyled is coming from Bootstrap):

CSS:

```
li.hot {
    list-style: inside url('../img/chili.png');
    direction: rtl;
}

li.vegetarian {
    list-style: inside url('../img/vegetarian.png');
    direction: rtl;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3>HOUSE SPECIALS</h3>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="hot">Gosht achar</li>
    <li class="vegetarian">Mixed vegetable dhansak</li>
    <li>Meti Gosht</li>
</ul>
```

However, there could be up to 5 chilis next to a menu item, and it could be both hot **AND** vegetarian. What would be the best way to combine them so that I could use something like the following syntax?

HTML:

```
<h3>HOUSE SPECIALS</h3>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <!-- The following would display chili.png repeated 5
         times to the right of the list item --> 
    <li class="xxxx-hot">Chicken phaal</li>
    <!-- The following would display chili.png and vegetarian.png
         to the right of the list item -->
    <li class="hot vegetarian">Vegetable biryani</li>
    <li>Meti Gosht</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via `::after` pseudo element

```
<ul>
    <li class="hot hot-1">Gosht achar</li>
    <li class="vegetarian">Mixed vegetable dhansak</li>
    <li class="hot hot-4">Chicken phaal</li>
    <li class="hot hot-1 vegetarian">Vegetable biryani</li>
    <li class="hot hot-3">Hot-3</li>
    <li class="hot hot-2 vegetarian">Hot-2, Vegetarian</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that I added `hot` class name for all hot dishes (besides their level), since those shares similar style.

Also keep in mind that I used two **16x16** image as chili and vegetarian, and all width/height are calculated accordingly. If your image is in different size, **change those number to fit your need**.

Common CSS:

```css
ul li.hot:after, /* CSS 2.1 syntax */
ul li.hot::after { /* CSS 3 syntax */
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    height:16px;
    background-image:url('../img/chili.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
ul li.hot.hot-1:after,
ul li.hot.hot-1::after {
    width:16px;
}
/* hot-2 ... hot-4 */
ul li.hot.hot-5:after,
ul li.hot.hot-5::after {
    width:80px;
}
ul li.vegetarian:after,
ul li.vegetarian::after {
    content:url('../img/vegetarian.png');
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Now you have two choices.

- If you want to display vegetarian first:

```css
ul li.hot.hot-1.vegetarian:after,
ul li.hot.hot-1.vegetarian::after {
    width:32px; /* 16+16 */
}
/* hot-2 ... hot-4 */
ul li.hot.hot-5.vegetarian:after,
ul li.hot.hot-5.vegetarian::after {
    width:96px; /* 80+16 */
}
```

[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92ckn/)

- If you want to display chili first:

```css
ul li.hot.vegetarian:after,
ul li.hot.vegetarian::after {
    width:16px;
}
ul li.hot.hot-1.vegetarian:after,
ul li.hot.hot-1.vegetarian::after {
    padding-left:16px;
}
/* hot-2 ... hot-4 */
ul li.hot.hot-5.vegetarian:after,
ul li.hot.hot-5.vegetarian::after {
    padding-left:80px;
}
```

[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92ckn/1/)

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Browser_Compatibility), this should work for IE>=8.